# How to prove that $(G, \cdot)$ structure is an Abelian group where $G$ is a set of matrices determined by a certain rule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I have a pretty tough algebra question for today. It is from a set of problem of a competition and I tried solving it. The problem has two parts the first is the following:

a.) Given the set $G = \{A(x)\mid x\in (-1,1)\}$, where $A(x)$ are the matrices of the form
$$A(x) = \frac {1}{\sqrt {(1-x^2)}}  \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & x \\ 0 & \sqrt{1-x^2} & 0 \\ x & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix},$$
prove that $(G, \cdot)$ is an Abelian-group where "$\cdot$" is matrix-multiplication.

b.) Prove that $f:G \rightarrow R$ $f(A(x)) = \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ is an isomorphism between $(G, \cdot)$ and $(R,+)$ groups.

It is clearly easy to prove that $A(x) \cdot A(y) = A(y) \cdot A(x)$, I just calculated both $A(x) \cdot A(y)$ and $A(y) \cdot A(x)$ and compared them. The problem is first we have to prove that $(G, \cdot)$ is a group and I was stuck when I needed to prove that $\forall \space A(x), A(y) \space \space  A(x) \cdot A(y) \in G$. So I failed to prove closure.
I also easily calculated that it always will have an inverse matrix, and also the identity matrix is a part of it, but how could I prove that $A(x)^{-1} \in G \space\forall \space A(x) \in G $?

Isomorphism is probably not that hard to prove if I can figure out the first, but unfortunately, I could not.

I would accept some help in proving that $(G, \cdot)$ is a group, on the inverse matrix and determining the formula for $A(x) \cdot A(y) = A(\alpha)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've already proven closure and commutivity and you say you have found the identity and proved every matrix has an inverse. Why aren't you done?

Comment: You say it is easy to prove the equation $A(x) \cdot A(y) = A(y) \cdot A(x)$. What method did you use to prove that equation? I ask because if you did it by an explicit computation of the two product matrices $A(x) \cdot A(y)$ and $A(y) \cdot A(x)$ and an explicit comparison of those two matrices, then I would imagine you could *also* compare that product to the format of a general element of $G$ that you give in your post. If you're still stuck on this point, then you should edit your post to explain in detail how you proved that equation.

Comment: @JohnDouma I could prove that every element has an inverse, the question is, if the inverse is part of G. I could not prove that. Also, I could not prove closure.

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, it was by an explicit comparison of those two matrices, I will add it in the question, thanks

Comment: You can probably compare determinants to ascertain what the inverse has to be.

Comment: Under the assumption that $f$ in (b) is an isomorphism of groups, then if $A(y) = A(x)^{-1}$, then $\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right) + \ln\left(\frac{1+y}{1-y}\right) = 0$.  Can you solve for $y$?  (This doesn't prove inverse elements exist, as such a conclusion is circular, but once you have a candidate $y$, you can directly show $A(y)$ is the inverse)

Comment: Should that constant out front be $1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring solving the equation you proposed gives $x=-y$ , can be a good point to try something I guess, thanks.

Comment: @eyeballfrog oh, yes, sorry, I missed the square root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easily checks that
$$A(x)A(y)=A\left(\frac{x+y}{1+xy}\right),$$ from which
$$f(A(x)A(y))=f(A(x))+f(A(y))$$
follows.
Since $f:G\to\Bbb R$ is moreover bijective, this proves *both* that $G$ is an abelian group and $f$ is an isomorphism.

Moreover, recognizing here above the formula for the [$\tanh$ of a sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Sums_of_arguments), one readily reparametrizes $G$ by letting $B(u)=A(\tanh u),$ thus obtaining $B(u)B(v)=B(u+v)$ and $f(A(x))=\operatorname{argtanh}(x).$

Comment: Thanks, nice solution. I could not figure out that $A(x)A(y) = A(\frac {x+y}{1+xy})$, but this helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

The limits $|x| < 1$ and the presence of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ suggest a trig substitution of $x = \sin\theta$ or $x = \tanh\eta$. The latter case shows more promise, giving
$$
A(\eta) = \begin{bmatrix}\cosh \eta & 0 & \sinh\eta \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \sinh\eta & 0 & \cosh\eta\end{bmatrix}
$$
which can be easily shown to satisfy $A(\eta)A(\nu) = A(\eta+\nu)$. This also leads nicely into part 2, since $\tanh^{-1}(x) = \ln[(1+x)/(1-x)]/2$.